# Networkx, using shortest paths to make shortest cycles

Tags: python, graph, networkx, shortest-path

this question is *specific* to NetworkX.  I could make my own functions to accomplish all the things I need, but it would take much longer so I want to avoid it.

The situation:

I have an unweighted graph, represented by a NetworkX Undirected Graph.  From this graph, I seek "shortest cycles" - that is to say, for a given node k, I am finding the shortest simple path (only passes through a node once), that leaves k and then comes back to k.

To accomplish this, I would like to use any NetworkX Shortest Paths algorithm, and do the search from node k, to node k.  The problem is, it seems that every shortest path algorithm simply returns node k as the path.  So, it never actually leaves.  And, I don't know how to change this.

A possible solution would be for me to do:

```
for each edge from k
    disconnect that edge
    do shortest path from the other side of that edge to k
    reconnect that edge
```

However, the sheer number of times I plan on doing this "shortest cycle" technique is extremely huge, and I would prefer to not have to do that.  So, is there an easier way to do what I want with NetworkX?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it necessary for it to be shortest path algorithm? Can't it be another networkx algorith?

Comment: If there is another networkx algorithm that will work well here, but I do not know of one that would be nearly as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `cycle_basis`, which tries to find a set of cycles that forms a basis and select the minimal cycle:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
g.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (2,7), (3,5), (6,7), (5,6), (1,5), (3,4)])

min(nx.cycle_basis(g, 1), key=lambda cycle: len(cycle))
```